# Create Volume Control with JavaScript and HTML 5

Tags: javascript, html

I am having trouble understanding an assignment that my lecturer gave me. He supplies us with a program that is supposed to record from the computer microphone and tells us, to build a volume control for it that controls the db for the loudspeaker. It just confuses me, because there is, as far as I can tell, no loudspeaker involved in this program.

```
<html>
<head>  
    <title>Audio Renderer -chrome</title>

    <style>
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>HTML5 webmic-Renderer </h1>
    <h4>Chrome</h4>
    <pre id="preLog">Access to micro</pre>


    <p>
        <input type="button" id="buttonStart" value="Start" onclick="start()" />
        <input type="button" id="buttonStop" value="Stop" onclick="stop()"  />
    </p>

<script>
var audioContext = new webkitAudioContext();
var realAudioInput = null;
var preLog ;
var zeroGain;
var channel = 2;
var bufferSize =1024;

function log(text){
            preLog = document.getElementById('preLog');
            if (preLog) preLog.textContent += ('\n' + text);
            else alert(text);
}
function start() {
        log('Get user media..');

        if (navigator.webkitGetUserMedia) navigator.webkitGetUserMedia({audio:true}, gotStream, noStream);
        else log('getUserMedia() not available from your Web browser!');
}

function noStream() {
            log('Access to Micro was denied!');
}

function gotStream(stream) {
    log('Access to Micro was started');
    // Create an AudioNode from the stream.
    realAudioInput = audioContext.createMediaStreamSource(stream);

    // Create an GainNode .
    zeroGain = audioContext.createGain();
    zeroGain.gain.value = 1.0;


        // create an audio node with 2 input and 1 output channels, and 1024 byte buffer size per audio frame
    jsNode = audioContext.createScriptProcessor(bufferSize, channel, channel-1);
    jsNode.onaudioprocess = audioProcess;

    // Signal Graph
    realAudioInput.connect( jsNode );
         // zeroGain.connect(??);
    jsNode.connect( audioContext.destination ); 
}

function stop() {
log('Access to Micro stopped');
    realAudioInput.disconnect(0);
}

  // this function is called every audio frame
  function audioProcess(event) {  
    var sampleIn_l  = event.inputBuffer.getChannelData(channel-2); // Stereo: 0 = left channel, 1 = right channel 
    var sampleIn_r  = event.inputBuffer.getChannelData(channel-1);
    var sampleOut = event.outputBuffer.getChannelData(channel-2); 

      // loop through every sample and add sample values to out buffer
      for(i = 0; i < event.inputBuffer.length; i++) {
        var sample_l = sampleIn_l[i]  ;
        var sample_r = sampleIn_r[i]  ;
        sampleOut[i] = ( sample_l );
      }
  } 

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

It says in his assignment: Create for the program Audio Renderer an interactive volume control for the loudspeaker on node-level: zeroGain.gain.value = 1.0;
I just don't understand what he wants from us. I would be so glad if anyone could help :)

Thank you very much for reading!

Comment: Isn't this a question that could best be answered by your lecturer?

Comment: Yes and No. A good lecturer should be able to do it, the problem is that he never answers any of our questions in a way that help. We tried before... many times. Also I will not see him for another week and mail replies come slowly, if at all.

Comment: The problem is this is about the nature of the work itself rather than a specific programming question and therefore not really suitable for StackOverflow.

Comment: Yeah, I almost figured. I just hoped that somebody would maybe find the really obvious thing that I couldn't see when looking at the code, because I just started with JavaScript and I thought that maybe the problem was just my understanding of the assignment, or lack there of.